# Calling Js script function from external Scripts

Tags: javascript, function

Am trying to call a JS script from a function library in another script.

Eg. iceCreams.Js contains  --->

```
iceCream(iceCreams){
var profit = .54

var Total = iceCreams * profits

return Total;

}
```

register.js contains -->

```
dailyTotals(wages, iceCreams){

var total = iceCream(iceCreams);

var profit = iceCreaps - wages

return wages;
}
```

Any help pointing me in the right direction?!

Comment: You are missing the `function` keywords btw.

Comment: ...and `iceCreaps` should probably be `iceCreams`. (Also recommend *not* relying on semicolon insertion; always include the semicolons required.)

Comment: Omitting semi-colons is bad practise. Using them willy-nilly is even worse. **Always** use semi-colons. It'll come back to haunt you when you start programming in a language which requires them.

Comment: So I dont have to point to it iceCream : iceCream(iceCreams)?

Comment: Please explain your last comment, I don't understand what you are trying to say...

Comment: I dont have to call to it as in refer to the script.

Comment: eg. someScript : iceCreams(500)

Comment: No. Every script you load will be put in the same scope (the global scope).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the javascripts is done in client side and after rendering the full html. So, you have to add script tag for the library javascripts before consuming ones.
Just add script tag for the library before the one for register:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="iceCreams.Js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="register.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your page loads the `iceCream.Js` before the `register.js`:

```
<html>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="iceCream.Js"></script>
<!-- now you can use functions in iceCream.Js in your register.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="register.js"></script>
....
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both script files must be referenced on the page they are used.

Additionally, to get IntelliSense in Visual Studio to work within the script, add the following line to the top of register.js:

```
/// <reference path="iceCreams.js" />
```